# Form submit to new tab, and redirect current window not working in Chrome / Safari

Tags: jquery, forms, google-chrome, redirect, onclick

I am trying to (1) make a form submit to an external website which should be launched in a new tab, while at the same time (2) redirect the browser window with the form to a thank you page.

My code works in Firefox, and Internet Explorer, and will do either part (1) or part (2) in Chrome / Safari if I remove the other part.

```
<script>
function testfunc() {
    alert('Submit Clicked');
    jQuery('form#getaQuote').submit();
    alert('Form submit attempted');
    window.location.href = ('http://ct.athiel.ca');
    alert('Redirect attempted');
}
</script>

<form id="getaQuote" action="http://www.winquote.net/complete.pl" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="testfunc()" />
</form>
```

You can try the code here ---> http://jsfiddle.net/GjyMd/7/

Any help would be appreciated, this problem is going over my head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GjyMd/10/)

javascript:

```
function testfunc() {
    alert('Submit Clicked');
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = ('http://ct.athiel.ca');
        alert('Redirect attempted');
    }, 1);
    jQuery('form#getaQuote').submit();
    alert('Form submit attempted');

}
```